# How to get the movies which are based on english novels using SPARQL in DBPEDIA

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

Using SPARQL, I am trying the get the list of all english novels and their properties.

I would also like to find if a movie was taken based on that novel and get the movie name and its director, If a movie relationship exists.

Code:

```
SELECT ?movie ?director ?book ?author ?publisher ?illustrator
WHERE {
?movie  dcterms:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:films> ;
        dbpedia-owl:basedOn     ?book .
?movie dbp:director ?director .

?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
?book dbp:author ?author .
?book dbp:publisher ?publisher .
?book dbp:illustrator ?illustrator .

}
limit 200
```

Comment: Ok,  and what didn't work about what you tried?

Comment: looks remarkably like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770201/fetching-a-list-of-books-adapted-into-films-from-dbpedia

Comment: I could not get any results once I added the movie part to the query...Probably, I was making some mistake in the category:films part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a lot of correct results, if you modify your query like this...

```
PREFIX     dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX         dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?book ?author ?movie ?director  ?publisher ?illustrator
WHERE {
?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
  OPTIONAL {?book dbp:author ?author .}
  OPTIONAL {?book dbp:publisher ?publisher .}
  OPTIONAL {?book dbp:illustrator ?illustrator .}
  OPTIONAL {?book ^dbpedia-owl:basedOn ?movie . ?movie a dbpedia-owl:Film }
  OPTIONAL {?movie dbp:director ?director .}
}
LIMIT 200
```

...but keep in mind that there are many movies that are not classified as `dbpedia-owl:Film`. Then of course you make a `union` with a few other popular classifications but that would still not guarantee there there won't be a movie based on a book, which will not be omitted.

And by the way what do you call "English novels" -- those written originally in English or those by English authors?

Comment: I meant those novels written originally in English