# Get movie(s) based on book(s) from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am new to SPARQL and trying to fetch a movie adapted from specific book from dbpedia. This is what I have so far:

```
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT *
WHERE 
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/page/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey> a ?type.
  ?type onto:basedOn ?book .
  ?book   a  onto:Book 
}
```

I can't get any results. How can I do that?

Comment: wrong namespace, wrong URI, wrong connection between first and second triple pattern (why should the type of the book be based on some other book?) and last but not least there is no `basedOn` relation for your example. Don't "invent" relations that do not exists, check for existing relations as Ivo Velitchkov described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668007/4744359).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I posted the prefix wrong. It must be `PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>`.

Comment: Looks like homework ... and like [How to get the movies which are based on english novels using SPARQL in DBPEDIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721789/how-to-get-the-movies-which-are-based-on-english-novels-using-sparql-in-dbpedia/) ... and like [Fetching a list of books adapted into films from dbpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770201/fetching-a-list-of-books-adapted-into-films-from-dbpedia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using any web resource, and in your case the property `:basedOn`, you need to make sure that you have declared the right prefix. If you are querying from the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint, then you can directly use `dbo:basedOn`even without declaring it, as it is among [predefined](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl). Alternatively, if you want to use your own, or if you are using another SPARQL client, make sure that whatever short name you choose for this property, you declare the prefix for http://dbpedia.org/ontology/.

Then, first, to get more result you may not restrict the type of the subject of this triple pattern, as there could be movies that actually not type as such. So, a query like this

```
select distinct *

{

?movie dbo:basedOn ?book .

?book a dbo:Book .

}
```

will give you lots of good results but not all. For example, the resource from your example will be missing. You can easily check test the available properties between these two resource with a query like this:

```
select  ?p

{
{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)> ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey> }

UNION

{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey> ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)>}
}
```

You'll get only one result:
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#seeAlso

(note that the URI is with 'resource', not with 'page')

Then you may search for any path between the two resource, using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916040/sparql-is-there-any-path-between-two-nodes), or find a combination of other patterns that would increase the number of results.